# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ValidatorCache'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to start my project at .net5 and get this exception

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 
'An exception was thrown while activating Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionInvokerFactory 
-> λ:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.IActionInvokerProvider[] 
-> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerProvider 
-> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerCache 
-> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder 
-> λ:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.IObjectModelValidator.'

Inner exception
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ValidatorCache' 
from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

Some ideas?

Comment: please give more context. Did it work before? Is it a new project? How did you build the project? etc etc

Comment: this project worked on net core 2.2 before
i am trying to change it to net5

Comment: Are you sure all your projects are updated to .net 5? Have you cleaned your project and thrown away the old .bin, .obj and .vs directories? Give more info on the steps taken. Upgrading .net core 2.2 to .net 5 is not trivial.

Comment: You need check if your nuget package or package reference contains `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ValidatorCache`, it does not match the version of .net 5. Update the version to match .net 5. Share the project file will be helpful to community to help resolve your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is FluentValidation, you need to upgrade it to the latest version.